# How to convert CSV to JSON in mule 4

Tags: mule

Is there easy way to convert CSV into JSON in mule 4? Currently I'm doing it as below.

```
 %dw 2.0
    output application/json
    ---
    (payload splitBy('\r\n')) map using( tmp = $ splitBy(',')) {
             id : tmp[0],
             name: tmp[1]
    }
```

Comment: use AnupamBhusari suggestion but you need to set the metadata of the input as CSV. Please refer to this link: https://docs.mulesoft.com/anypoint-studio/v/6/input-output-structure-transformation-studio-task

Comment: is you file on windows machine as you are replacing \r\n on it? I am getting same issue too. Below answers doesn't work

Answer (score 2):

Try with following

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
---
payload
```

Input :-

```
id,name
2,Tom
3,Jerry
```

And output produced is

```
[
  {
    "id": "2",
    "name": "Tom"
  },
  {
    "id": "3",
    "name": "Jerry"
  }
]
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Best working solution, if you have a CSV with comma separated values and a first row with header is:

FIRST TRANSFORM MESSAGE

```
%dw 2.0
output application/csv headerLineNumber=0, header=true
---
payload
```

SECOND TRANSFORM MESSAGE

```
%dw 2.0
output application/dw
---

payload
```

Answer (score -1):

Try following in Transform message

%dw 2.0

### output application/json

payload map {
    FirstName: $.FirstName,
    LastName : $.LastName,
    Department : $.Department,
    Email : $.Email,
    Phone : $.Phone,
    CreatedDate : $.CreatedDate
}